# Bug in Mobile Safari regarding HTML LINK

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, safari, hyperlink

My native iPhone app displays HTML files using UIWebView. These HTML files are stored locally on the iPhone (they ship with the app).

Now I'm also trying to use a central CSS file in the HTML files, using something like:
`<link href="../../stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

In Safari, this works, the HTML files look OK.
In Mobile Safari (both on the simulator and a real device) this does not work: no CSS file found.
So I tried the following:
Store the CSS file in the same directory as the HTML file (plus different LINK of course): no problem.
Store the CSS file one directory higher: no problem, works in both Safari and mobile Safari.
Store the CSS file one directory higher: does not work in mobile Safari, but no problem in Safari.
What gives? In `../..` are various other directories that I created and use. 
Note: `../..` points to a directory that is an immediate subdirectory of the bundle. `../..` does not try to go into the bundle directory.

Any ideas? Anyone who saw me demonstrate this was also baffled.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Caused by a bug of my own combined with a mobile Safari "feature".

The HTML file was opened with a path containing `//` That was my bug.
Using `../..` to traverse back caused the strange behavior observed above. That's a mobile Safari feature for you. I am used to `//` being treated as a single `/`, but apparently mobile Safari begs to differ.

Just cost me some hair... never mind.

Comment: Thanks for posting the behavior. This could be useful for others.